# How to return all key with most frequently repeated values from an array by Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to get all the keys with the max value.

```
# I want 6 and 2 since they both of them occurred three times.
arr = [5, 6, 2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 2]
```

I tried this but it returns 6 only.

```
# this returns {5=>2, 6=>3, 2=>3, 1=>1}
freq = hash.inject(Hash.new(0)){ |h, v| h[v] += 1; h }
# then I use max_by, but this gives only 6
p arr.max_by{ |v| freq[v]}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit misleading: 'I want to get all the keys with the max value.' - max value in your array is 6 but then you ask for 2 as well... Do you want the most frequently repeated values?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I was thinking about freq hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would propose a `group_by` on the number of occurrences of unique values in the original Array, followed by taking the values of the mapping with the highest number:

```
arr = [5, 6, 2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 2]
arr.uniq.group_by { |v| arr.count(v) }.max.last
# [6, 2]
```

The `group_by` yields a `Hash` with the number of occurrences as keys and unique elements of `arr` with that number of occurrences as values. The `.max` call will then yield the mapping with the highest key, and `.last` will take only the values which we were interested in.

Comment: Argh! I felt I was missing something :) I would use `[1]` instead of `.last`, is more coherent with _I want the second value of an array converted from an hash_, instead of _I want the last element of an array_

Comment: I get NoMethodError: undefined method `group_by' for [5, 6, 2, 1]:Array. http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/926ab

Comment: @shin It's in [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), at least for Ruby 2.0+, which version are you using? edit; and also for [1.9](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

Comment: Ok, let me check... Yep it works with 2.1.1. So rubyfiddle must be 1.8 then.

Comment: @shin I cannot find information about which version of Ruby is used by rubyfiddle.com, but clearly it's not up to date or just bugged. Even [1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) had it ;(

Comment: @Daniël Knippers: Can you edit just a bit so that I can give an up-vote?

Comment: @shin Done, added a bit more descriptive text.

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
arr = [5, 6, 2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 2]

uniques = arr.uniq
max_count = uniques.map { |v| arr.count(v) }.max
max_values = uniques.select { |v| arr.count(v) == max_count }
#=> [6, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think as

```
arr.group_by(&:to_i).each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h| 
   (h[v.size] ||= []) << k 
end.max_by(&:first).last # => [6, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [5, 6, 2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 2]
freq = arr.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, v| h[v] += 1; h }   

max = freq.max[1]
freq.keep_if { |h, v| v == max }.keys
# => [6, 2]
```

The code is pretty self explanatory. I'm just using your code up until `freq.keep_if`. `freq.max` returns an array in the form [6, 3] (6 being the number, 3 being the occurrences), so freq.max[1] is the number of occurrences. `.keys` returns all the keys in an array, which gets rid of the occurrences.